# how to remove duplicate values in excel for import in windows form application in DataGrid view and save in SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        String one = "INSERT INTO empl (e_id,f_name,l_name,address) Values (@e_id, @f_name,@l_name, @address)";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(one, con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        con.Open();
        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e_id", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["e_id"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["f_name"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_name", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["l_name"].Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["address"].Value);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }

        cmd.Dispose();
        MessageBox.Show("Excel Upload in Datbase");
        con.Close();


        cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM empl");
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Connection = con;
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: remove duplicate values and import my excel file in database